# Using carlosHE OAuth2 server in Delphi 11

Tags: rest, delphi, oauth-2.0

For projects that will take place in the future, it is important that my own REST server will be created. Now, I have been working on this for a few weeks, and everything concerning the REST server is ready. I can give requests and receive responses. I am just missing the security through OAuth2.

After some research, I found the authorization server from [carlosHE](https://github.com/CarlosHe/oauth2-server). Now, I have everything installed in Delphi, but I do not understand how I can get the authorization workable for my REST server.

Are there people who have experience with applying the OAuth2 protocol to REST servers using [carlosHE/oauth2-server](https://github.com/CarlosHe/oauth2-server)? Or, maybe there are other ways that work?

Comment: REST servers typically do not require OAUTH2 but some kind of token for authorization. Getting the token is done with a separate service.

Comment: It's a shame there are no demos there. You could try [filing an issue](https://github.com/CarlosHe/oauth2-server/issues) in the repo.

Comment: @DaveNottage yes I thought I didn't look properly but so there appears to be no demo I will make a report of it. And if the demo is available I will set it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draft answer:

- The client must get an access token from the OAuth2 server. (how to authenticate the client is a different question)
- The access token must be stored server-side, so that the REST server can validate client REST requests.
- The client then can send REST requests which contain the access token. (typically sent as a HTTP header value)

Comment: thank you! now I have a clearer picture of how to add oauth2.

Comment: If this answer was helpful you may accept it